# iPhone reports 6GB of photos I can't find

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photos

My gallery is totally empty but in my usage it appears that 6.3 GB are used by 'photos and camera' and when i click on photos and camera photo stream is 4 KB and photo library is 6.2 GB.

Comment: Try to be more clear with your title next time.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the photos app, make sure you click through all tabs at the bottom. Maybe you're in an album or stream. If that doesn't help, connect your iPhone to a computer to access the photos.